# Interpolation of a "bit by bit" Function

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, piecewise

I am facing a problem with integrating a function. I have to integrate the function "bit by bit". This is the smallest working example that shows the problem:

```
n = 25;
dz = 1300/n;
pBF = FunctionInterpolation[
       Piecewise[{{9890/3, 500 <= z <= 800}}], 
       {z, 0, 1300}, InterpolationOrder -> 1
      ];
data = Prepend[0]@Table[Integrate[pBF[z] z, {z, (j - 1) dz, j dz}], {j, n}];
Data = Accumulate[data];
DataInt = Interpolation[Table[{k dz, Data[[k + 1]]}, {k, 0, n}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Insted of creating an InterpolatingFunction Mathematica prints the two error messages:

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.026557142857,0,52}.
>   NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.026557142857142856` cannot be used as an iterator.

The strange thing with this is the fact that when I look at the data-points in a `ListPlot` the function should not be hard to interpolate. The picture shows the `ListPlot`.[image: scatter plot of calculated data obtained from ListPlo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `NIntegrate` and defining the `AccuracyGoal` and the `MinRecursion` option for this function.

```
data2 = Prepend[0]@
   Table[NIntegrate[pBF[z] z, {z, (j - 1) dz, j dz}, 
     MinRecursion -> 9, AccuracyGoal -> 5], {j, n}];
```

The interpolation is also working as seen in the picture:
[image: Interpolation of Data]